# Browsing VisualWorks code in Squeak/Pharo

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, visualworks

Is there any Smalltalk parser in Squeak/Pharo which allows me to browse VisualWorks code in Squeak/Pharo ? I'm interested in reading code exported in the chunk format (not in XML).

Clarification: I do not need to file in the code.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean file it in and then being able to explore it using a system/class browser while not worrying about compilation issues arising from missing classes/differences in classes?

Answer (score 3):

You could save as a monticello package, then use the package browser to look at it.

Comment: How do you save as Monticello in VisualWorks?

Answer (score 1):

At Esug2012 Dale Henrichs presented some work to use git/github and a file-based model for smalltalk source code. He worked with others on at least squeak/pharo/gemstone and visualworks versions

Answer (score 1):

There is a `FileOut30` package in Store that allows you to file out code in VW so that Pharo understands it. The file browser should be able to display the code without loading.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happens with VisualWorks code, but In pharo, with regular code you can drag  a SMalltalk chunk format file and drop it in the "world" and you will get a  popup menu with different options, like browsing the code. I guess that doesn't try to compile so you may be able to browse de VW code...I don't know, just try :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use MOOSE for this (especially if you have more advanced needs). The old version on VW can create an export that can be read by MOOSE on Pharo (using the Famix2Importer package).